# How to implement a loop from the middle to the beginning of the sequence using iterators?

Tags: c++, loops, iterator

I want to iterate over a collection from the middle to the beginning but I'm not sure about best way to implement it. Another thing that complicates it is that I have a function where I have to pass an iterator. Code explaining my problem:

First approach:

```
template <typename RandomIt>
void Example(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
    auto size = std::distance(first, last);
    RandomIt middle = std::next(first, size / 2 - 1);
    for (auto i = middle; ; --i)
    {
        OtherFunction(i);
        if (i == first) break;
    }
}
```

Second approach:

```
template <typename RandomIt>
void Example(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
    auto size = std::distance(first, last);
    RandomIt middle = std::next(first, size / 2 - 1);
    auto rmiddle = std::make_reverse_iterator(std::next(middle, 1));
    auto rlast = std::make_reverse_iterator(first);
    for (auto i = rmiddle; i != rlast; ++i)
        OtherFunction(i.base()- 1);
}
```

Each one is not really intuitive. First one has infinite loop with break and the second one has that long definition of rmiddle and I have to pass iterator as i.base()- 1, not really easy to read. I would need something like do-while but first checking the condition, then executing code even if condition is false and then ending a loop. Is there a better way or a pattern how to deal with something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach has an issue because you do not follow usual pattern - use [first,last[ for the range, you are trying to use [first,last] (last is included):

```
template <typename RandomIt>
void Example(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
    auto size = std::distance(first, last);
    RandomIt middle = std::next(first, size / 2);
    for (auto i = middle; i != first;)
    {
        OtherFunction(--i);
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, the standard uses ")" for an open upper bound, not "[".

Comment: Yea, I used different notation, should be still clear though

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
template <typename RandomIt> ...
```

I am assuming you have a RandomAccesssIterator.

[*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) supports the greater-than operator. You can use:

```
// Take care of all items except first in the loop.
for (auto i = middle; i > first; --i)
{
    OtherFunction(i);
}

// Take care of first
OtherFunction(first);
```